# I don't understand why my code can't adopted css when i try

Tags: html, css

I just try to adopted css code from codepen 
so i copy&paste and use external link but it's not show like codepen 
just show to me background body color 
why this happend?

I reference code from here 
https://codepen.io/MelonBoxer/pen/eopWar

I don't understand because every copy&paste from codepen was working but it's not

**This is my html code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./test.css">
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="blog-card spring-fever">
    <div class="title-content">
      <h3>SPRING FEVER</h3>
      <hr />
      <div class="intro">Yllamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo.</div>
    </div><!-- /.title-content -->
    <div class="card-info">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim.
    </div><!-- /.card-info -->
    <div class="utility-info">
      <ul class="utility-list">
        <li class="comments">12</li>
        <li class="date">03.12.2015</li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.utility-info -->
    <!-- overlays -->
    <div class="gradient-overlay"></div>
    <div class="color-overlay"></div>
  </div><!-- /.blog-card -->
  </body>
</html>
```

**This is my CSS**

```
  @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700);
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic);

    // variables
    $card-width:  350px;
    $card-height: 500px;
    $h-color:     #9CC9E3;
    $yellow:      #D0BB57;
    $txt-color:   #DCE3E7;

    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    body{
      background: #323c41;
    }

    .blog-card{
      width: $card-width;
      height: $card-height;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      margin: -250px 0 0 -175px;
      overflow: hidden;
      border-radius: 10px;
      box-shadow: 3px 3px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
      text-align: center;

      &.spring-fever{
        background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1765/bg-blog-card.jpg) no-repeat;
      }

      .color-overlay{
        /* Rectangle 11: */
        background: rgba(84,104,110,0.4);
        width: $card-width;
        height: $card-height;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 10;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        transition: background .3s cubic-bezier(.33,.66,.66,1);
      }
      .gradient-overlay{
        /* bg-gradient: */
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,.6) 21%);
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,.6) 21%);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,.6) 21%);
        background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,.6) 21%);
        width: $card-width;
        height: $card-height;
        position: absolute;
        top: 350px;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 15;
      }

      &:hover{

        .card-info{
          opacity: 1;
          bottom: 120px;
        }
        .color-overlay{
          background: rgba(84,104,110,0.8);
        }
      }
    }

    .title-content{
      text-align: center;
      margin: 70px 0 0 0;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 20;
      width: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
    h3{
      font-size: 20px;
      font-weight: 500;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
      color: $h-color;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    hr{
      width: 50px;
      height: 3px;
      margin: 20px auto;
      border: 0;
      background: $yellow;
    }
    .intro{
      width: 170px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      color: $txt-color;
      font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
      font-size: 13px;
      font-style: italic;
      line-height: 18px;
    }
    .card-info{
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 100px;
      left: 0;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 0 50px;
      color: $txt-color;
      font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
      font-style: 16px;
      line-height: 24px;
      z-index: 20;
      opacity: 0;
      transition: bottom .3s, opacity .3s cubic-bezier(.33,.66,.66,1);
    }

    .utility-info{
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 20;
    }
    .utility-list{
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0 0 30px 20px;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%;

      li{
        margin: 0 15px 0 0;
        padding: 0 0 0 22px;
        display: inline-block;
        color: $txt-color;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;

        &.comments{
          background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1765/icon-chat.svg) no-repeat 0 .1em;
        }
        &.date{
          background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1765/icon-calendar.svg) no-repeat 0 .1em;
        }
      }
    }
```

i want to see just in my local place like from codepen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The person who create the codepen used SCSS (or Sass). You needed to compile that code into css. This can be done in codepen by clicking on the dropdown in the css window and selecting "View Compiled CSS". I copy and pasted that compiled css and html below:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic);
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #323c41;
}

.blog-card {
  width: 350px;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -250px 0 0 -175px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
}
.blog-card.spring-fever {
  background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1765/bg-blog-card.jpg) no-repeat;
}
.blog-card .color-overlay {
  /* Rectangle 11: */
  background: rgba(84, 104, 110, 0.4);
  width: 350px;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: background 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.33, 0.66, 0.66, 1);
}
.blog-card .gradient-overlay {
  /* bg-gradient: */
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 21%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 21%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 21%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 21%);
  width: 350px;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 350px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 15;
}
.blog-card:hover .card-info {
  opacity: 1;
  bottom: 120px;
}
.blog-card:hover .color-overlay {
  background: rgba(84, 104, 110, 0.8);
}

.title-content {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 70px 0 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 20;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: #9CC9E3;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

hr {
  width: 50px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 0;
  background: #D0BB57;
}

.intro {
  width: 170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #DCE3E7;
  font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-style: italic;
  line-height: 18px;
}

.card-info {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100px;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 50px;
  color: #DCE3E7;
  font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
  font-style: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  z-index: 20;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: bottom 0.3s, opacity 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.33, 0.66, 0.66, 1);
}

.utility-info {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 20;
}

.utility-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 0 30px 20px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.utility-list li {
  margin: 0 15px 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 22px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #DCE3E7;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.utility-list li.comments {
  background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1765/icon-chat.svg) no-repeat 0 0.1em;
}
.utility-list li.date {
  background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1765/icon-calendar.svg) no-repeat 0 0.1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./test.css">
      </head>
      <body>
          <div class="blog-card spring-fever">
        <div class="title-content">
          <h3>SPRING FEVER</h3>
          <hr />
          <div class="intro">Yllamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo.</div>
        </div><!-- /.title-content -->
        <div class="card-info">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim.
        </div><!-- /.card-info -->
        <div class="utility-info">
          <ul class="utility-list">
            <li class="comments">12</li>
            <li class="date">03.12.2015</li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.utility-info -->
        <!-- overlays -->
        <div class="gradient-overlay"></div>
        <div class="color-overlay"></div>
      </div><!-- /.blog-card -->
      </body>
    </html>
```